# IE9 not displaying dynamic data in table in print preview

Tags: printing, internet-explorer-9, preview, css-tables

I have a table that I'm populating from a database and when I do a print preview on the page, `IE9` shows no data. `IE7` and `IE8` show the data in all the rows of the table.

I'm not sure why `IE9` does not show it. It just has the header row.

`IE9` is in `Standards mode`. I did try switching to `Quirks mode` in `IE9` in the Developer Tools and the data showed up.

Right now the page is in a Dev environment and not available to the to outside world. Not sure if that has anything to do with it but I would think (perhaps wrongly) that it would affect `IE7` & `IE8` as well.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Suffering from the same problem any luck with this?

Comment: I am also having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a floated parent element, try setting the element to `float:none`.

You should only need to apply this to the highest parent element.

Answer (score 0):

Try to give the table a width and height via css, this worked for me.

```
@media print {

    table.your-table-class {
        width: 99%;
        height: 100%;
    }
}
```